no kaleido source distribution or wheel for uv on current platform
kaleido does not seem to work currently in a uv venv.
is there a workaround?
tried to output plotly static figs to .jpg
this depends on kaleido
Example:
f = px.scatter(
    x=[1,2,3],
    y=[4,5,6]
)
f.write_image('figtest.jpg')

produces

ValueError:
Image export using the "kaleido" engine requires the kaleido package,
which can be installed using pip:
$ pip install -U kaleido

I'm using uv, so rather than pip install I add kaleido to the projects pyproject.toml file. This produces:

error: Distribution kaleido==0.2.1.post1 @ registry+https://pypi.org/simple can't be installed because it doesn't have a source distribution or wheel for the current platform

Current platform is Apple M1 Pro, MacOS 15.1.1 (24B91)
Am I out of luck in uv for now?

I was running into the same issue with kaleido (python 3.13, running on ubuntu  wsl)
I could install uv add kaleido==0.2.0, might work for you if you do not specifically need 0.2.1

Thanks—can't recall if I tried this, will give it a spin. Also saw this recently, hoping it may resolve the issue: https://community.plotly.com/t/major-releases-of-plotly-and-dash-narwhals-dash-hooks-and-more/89272#p-187019-major-overhaul-of-kaleido-6
